# Global method to prevent app from crashing?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add a method in my parent activity that all my activities are inheriting from. I want the method to catch any errors that have not already been handled so the app does not crash. Instead of crashing it will redirect to a failure screen activity.

Here is what I have at the moment but it does not work, the app freezes and then goes black:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread, Throwable paramThrowable) {
            redirectToFailureScreen();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is in your redirectToFailureScreen?

Comment: There is no such thing. Test your app and `try`/`catch` anywhere it could fail (network, disk, memory, user input...) and handle those errors correctly. Then give the app to some monkeys and/or users to test and break. Fix those errors. Then repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uncaught exception handler is not meant for rescuing an application. Ending up in that handler means the thread is being terminated. The handler gets notified as a courtesy for logging purposes before the thread is killed.

> Implemented by objects that want to handle cases where a thread is
>   being terminated by an uncaught exception. Upon such termination, the
>   handler is notified of the terminating thread and causal exception. If
>   there is no explicit handler set then the thread's group is the
>   default handler.